# come a time when you will be the ancestor

Tags: phrase-meaning

The phrase "come a time when you will be the ancestor" sounds to me to mean "come a time when you're the only survival (except your wife or husband) on Earth". I am not sure it is what Dawkins meant.

What does it mean to you native speakers?

> Richard Dawkins tweeted just now:

There will **come a time when you will be the ancestor** of either every human on Earth or none.

Comment: _There will come a time when_ means _at some time in the [distant] future_.

Comment: Thanks. But it is still not clear to me. In future can someone be the ancestor of every human?

Comment: Yes, and an ancestor is someone you are descended from - your parents, plus their parents, and their parents' parents, and so on..

Comment: What he is saying is true if certain things don't change; we have more than one child, on average, so over time our descendants grown in number exponentially, but the number of people who can fit on the Earth ultimately has limits.

Comment: I mean, really, what settles it for me is that the Earth will eventually be destroyed, probably swallowed by our sun's red giant phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To state Dawkins' idea more clearly:

- Imagine the year is 10,000 AD:
- Option 1: Every human on earth can trace their ancestry back to you (because you had children)
- Option 2: No human on earth can trace their ancestry back to you (because you had no children)

Note that "there will come a time" is just another way of saying "a time will come".

Comment: Thank you. I don't quite understand the phrase "Option 1: Every human on earth can trace their ancestry back to you (because you had children)" - It would mean you (and your wife or husband) have to be the only survived couple on this planet in the first place, which appears to be statistically impossible given so many people would do anything to survive.

Comment: Not necessarily. Assuming your family line doesn't die out, the longer the time that  passes, the greater the chance that any individual alive is ultimately descended from you.

Comment: Yes, and you can easily see how there would be a hard limit on the number of generations it would take to guarantee option 1 if you use a simple model of reproduction (no incest, each child has two biological parents, etc). Each child has two parents, four grandparents, eight great-grandparents, 16 great-great-grandparents, ... it only takes 33 generations to get to 8 billion, so assuming 30 years per generation, option 1 could be true (in our simple model) by the year 3000.